# Remote ipython kernel not displaying plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, x11-forwarding

My setup is that I run an ipython notebook remotely on a linux server and I connect to it from OSX via an ssh tunnel.

I can confirm that X forwarding works fine and from the same terminal where ipython is started from I can use gnuplot etc.

In the ipython session on my local machine when trying to do something like

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("GTK3cairo")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],'*-')
```

all I get is `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x54bcc90>]`. I have tried various other backends, with the same results. When using `%pylab inline` the plots appear, but I'd like them in separate windows.

I suppose something is wrong with X forwarding still - what would be the best way to debug this? All suggestions welcome.

Comment: did you try `plt.show()` ?

Comment: Instead of an ssh tunel  you can access the ipython notebook through a browser on your LAN using http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html

Comment: @plonser: that sorted it out, thanks!!!!

Comment: @wrdeman: I have actually been doing that - what I really meant is that I access the server via an ssh tunnel.

Comment: 1) don't use %pylab , use %matplotlib, 2) kernels are runned in sub-process that might not inherit the environment variable, so no X-Forward.

Answer (score 2):

1. When connecting to the server, use `-L` (which does local port forwarding) instead of `-X` (which does graphical output forwarding) like this:

   ```
   ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 your_user_name@your_server_ip
   ```
2. In your code, use `%matplotlib inline` before you import the `pyplot` to load the backend upfront and end with `;` like this:

   ```
   %matplotlib inline
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

   plt.figure()
   plt.imshow(sample_image)
   plt.show();
   ```

Comment: Very helpfull, thanks ! No need to end with `;`